# which edition of websphere client to use?

Tags: ibm-mq

The Websphere MQ's edition is 7.0.1,and I want use a WebSphere MQ client to implement messaging and queuing. Which edition of WebSphere MQ client should I use ?

Comment: If you want people to answer you, you should start to mark the answer which is most helpful to your previous questions. This gives people the motivation to help you and also is polite.

Comment: I'm so sorry.I will.And about this question,I think I need to use the latest edition of Websphere MQ client.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of WebSphere MQ Client can talk to all versions of WebSphere MQ queue manager.  If you use the latest version you benefit from the latest fixes and performance enhancements but in terms of function you are limited by the back-level QMgr.  You don't *lose* any function that you would get by using the same version client as QMgr, you just cant wring v7.1 function out of a v7.0 QMgr by using the v7.1 client.

As a rule, use the latest client.

That said, here are your download links:

[WMQ Client v7.1](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71)
[WMQ Client v7.0](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7)

The only wrinkle is the client-side differences.  For configuring the client, use the Infocenter that matches the client version.  To see which functionality to expect from the QMgr, use the Infocenter that matches the QMgr.

[WMQ V7.1 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp)
[WMQ V7.0 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp)

Comment: Thank you!T.Rob.I have downloaded the latest version of MQ client.